# ALFRESCO PHP CMIS API :: How to create custom property for a file

Tags: php, api, alfresco

I am using alfresco repository.
I downloaded the source from 
 
 https://code.google.com/p/php-alf-cmis-api
BASIC repository and object handling [Create, upload, download, delete, change properties] is happening 
I can change basic ASPECTS like TITLE and DESCRIPTION also.

But there is no such option to add custom properties.

I want to add custom properties for a file.
Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well you want to create custom types and then work with types that satisfy your company.

You need to create alfresco model and in this model you should define custom types, aspects and so on. Then you will be able to set values to custom properties of your types/aspects.

1: I would advise to use alfresco maven sdk
2: create module
3: create model inside
4: work with integration-test until you are satisfied with the results
5: deploy to your server and then use

You can find how to create module, models aspects and deploy here
http://alfrescoblog.com/2014/05/10/maven-alfresco-sdk/ .

Hope this helps.

Edit:
 Then you apply your custom aspects to a file and you add custom properties to it.

Comment: I need a PHP based library.